# What are the differences between Android's RelativeLayout and iOS's AutoLayout?

Tags: android, ios, swift, autolayout, android-relativelayout

I've been developing for some years in `Android`, now I'm approaching the `swift` and `iOS` world.

I cannot understand how the `AutoLayout` engine works (and to be honest I didn't understand either the lifecycle of a `screen activity` in ios).

When I develop in `Android`, I set to `relative layout`, I set the reference to the other object and then I got it works fine.

In `iOS`, although I set the `autolayout`, I set the "`pin`" between objects each others, and so on, but it's not what I was expecting.

Can anyone can suggest to me any guides to  help figure it out and understand how iOS works.

What relationship is there with `storyboard` and `views`? May I add more `views` in `storyboard`, and each `view` is controlled by a `UiView Cocoa touch class`?

Comment: "it's not how I was expecting" so what do you expect?

Comment: For example, I'm following the Apple tutorial. I don't like copy and paste code from tutorial, I like to see which is the result, and try to code it myself, and then see if it is like the one on the tutorial.

These are the steps I followed:
add view to storyboard;
add buttons to view;
set the button high as the container view (I think this is the mistake)
set pin distance between buttons. 
set image to button (like background).

The result was that the image button was much more big than what I was expecting.

In android I had the chance to set "wrap_content" or something like that

Comment: Here I don't know how to do this. If you can advice me a good guide to autolayout, I'll study that because, from apple official tutorial, to me it's not so understandable.

Comment: so you already know where the problem could be, try this https://www.raywenderlich.com/115440/auto-layout-tutorial-in-ios-9-part-1-getting-started-2 and mostly play with it to learn

Answer (score 0):

If you are an Android developer, you may know constraint layout from Android Studio version 2.2, it likes Auto Layout in iOS.